# Is there a fix/hack to get the stackdriver agents running on Amazon linux 2?

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver, amazon-eks, google-cloud-logging

Although the official documentation does not list Amazon Linux 2 among the supported OS', was wondering if there is a hacky way to get the agents running?

Comment: Have a look at this thread https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-fluentd/issues/136. There are some workarounds that could be helpful for you.

Comment: yes, been there before, but it does not address the problem with starting the service unfortunately